# Siteminder (maybe) 500 error issues

Tags: sql-server, solr, jboss, siteminder

We have been using JBoss Wildfly 8.2 for about 9 months and never had this issue until about two weeks ago (Nov 9th 2015 approximately). We use IIS 7.5 on Windows 2008R2. We serve .war files with Java/JavaScript and also server ColdFusion separately. We connect to MSSQL Server 2012. All of this has been the same with out the errors. We also use Spring and SOLR. We use SiteMinder.

What happens:

1. User goes to our website, they see a blank screen with the IE11 tab stating 500 error. After some minutes, the user can refresh and the site will be up fine. We have confirmed that two users at once will experience the same thing. As far as suspected browser configuration issues, the user does not need to do anything. They just wait 5-15 mins and then click refresh. Now that I think of it ... maybe the 500 error resolves after I have logged in remotely, but I am not 100% sure.
2. This does not happen every day, and we have 4 different sites with the exact same software and VM setup (IIS / .war file / etc is the same) and it happens to different sites randomly.
3. It is ALWAYS the first users in the morning that I have seen so far.
4. There are no server logs after 02:00 AM ... the site is trying to be accessed at around 6:00 AM. JBoss shows no indication of any errors and everything looks just fine in the back end. Our last error is: 23 Nov 15 02:00:03,915 ERROR [stderr] (Timer-6) java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect -- this is expected since that is DB maintenance time. After that ... nothing.
5. The Application Logs in Server Manager show the following at the time of the 500 error:

> New virus definition file loaded

Then 6+ occurrences:

> Failed to initialize the message bus
>
> SiteMinder agent has encountered initialization errors and will not service requests
>
> Server already running Duplicate LLAWP processes not allowed, exiting

Then I log into the server successfully and shortly after I see

> The Software Protection service is starting

Then, random or not, the site seems to be up and logs say Software Protection service has started.

What the heck is going on and how do I fix this? It seems coincidental that the 500 server error goes away after I log in, but still...

Comment: Does your antivirus software something like exmaining incoming/outgoing HTTP trafic? Then, when it restarts, it can disrupt ongoing connections.

Comment: I don't manage that software, but SiteMinder does SSO.

Comment: Wouldn't it be nice for the app to shut it down before the DB goes away?

Comment: It is 2017 now -- and this is still happening on a 2012 R2 server. Now, the error will disappear without logging it but it remains a mystery.